# case class Java bean combination -how to avoid some boilerplate

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a `case class` like this

```
  case class MyModel(category:Option[String],deploymentId:Option[String],key:Option[String],metaInfo:Option[String],name:Option[String],version:Option[Int],tenantId:Option[String])
```

There is a Java library, our app is interacting with which returns Java Bean. Now on many occasions have to populate Java Bean from `MyModel` `case class` e.g.

```
    val javaModel = repositoryService.newModel()

    myModel.category.map(javaModel.setCategory(_))
    myModel.deploymentId.map(javaModel.setDeploymentId(_))
    myModel.key.map(javaModel.setKey(_))
    myModel.metaInfo.map(javaModel.setMetaInfo(_))
    myModel.name.map(javaModel.setName(_))
    myModel.tenantId.map(javaModel.setTenantId(_))
    myModel.version.map(javaModel.setVersion(_))

    repositoryService.saveModel(javaModel)
```

Above is shorten snippet but it gets quite versbose with a ton of other properties in `MyModel` which corrosponds to `javaModel`. I am trying to come up with a generic function which iterates through `case class` (`MyModel`) and finds property names from `case class` members and calls appropriate `setter` on `javaModel` Java bean.

I know I can use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) for getting all `keys` (property names) from `case class` as follow

```
val modelLabel = LabelledGeneric[MyModel]
val modelKeys = Keys[modelLabel.Repr].apply
```

Now I am wondering if there is a way to use `modelKey` e.g. say when it finds `category`, when `mapping` over `modelKeys`, call appropriate `set` method on `javaModel`. e.g. for `category` it'll be calling `setCategory` and likewise for other properties (this may sound odd but preferably without using reflection? )

Comment: Is there, or could there be, a `repositoryService.newModel(... ctor args ...)` method? If there is there might be something you could do with shapeless.

Comment: @MilesSabin : Unfortunately I am dealing with cryptic Java library which doesn't have `repositoryService.newModel(... ctor args ...)`. It's mutable in nature where only returns `Model` by it's factory API `repositoryService.newModel()` - and then expects program to call its `setter` methods to set its property values. Looks like I am out of luck here?